# Python save as/open

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

hello there
i am making a text editor in Tkinter (python)
and so i made a menu and wanted to know how i can call a function that will display the windows Save-as or open boxes that every program uses.
For example in notepad you can click file-save and then it opens the windows save box.
I already have the menu but how can  i open the save box.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread39327.html:

```
import tkFileDialog

def open_it():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    print filename  # test

def save_it():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    print filename  # test

def save_as():
    filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
    print filename  # test
```